# Problems creating html layout using float and margin-left

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code that displays some DIV elements on a page.

```html
<div style="float: left; width:182px; height:200px; border-style: solid; border-width:1px">Left Column</div>
<div style="margin-left: 200px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px">

  <div style="float: left; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;">Div1</div>
  <div style="float: left; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;">Div2</div>
  <div style="clear:left; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;">Div3</div>
  <div style="float: left; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;">Div4</div>
</div>
```

I would like Div3 to be shown just below Div1 and Div2, but instead it is shown where the left column ends, so there is a large space between div1/div2 and div3.

How can I get div3 to be shown just below div1/div2? It is also important the div3 uses the whole available width.

Answer (score 0):

use this may help u

```
<div style="float: left; width:182px; height:200px; border-style: solid; border-width:1px">Left Column</div>
<div style="margin-left: 200px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px">

  <div style="float: left; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;">Div1</div>
  <div style="border-style: solid;border-width:1px;">Div2</div>
  <div style="border-style: solid;border-width:1px; display:block;">Div3</div>
  <div style="border-style: solid;border-width:1px; display:block">Div4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
border: 1px solid #000;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar{
float: left;
width:27%;
height: 200px;
}
.content{
float: left;
width: 70%;
margin-left: 3%;
}
.content:after{
content: '';
clear: both;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">Left Column</div>
<div class="content">

  <div style="float: left; ">Div1</div>
  <div style="float: left;">Div2</div>
  <div style="clear:left;">Div3</div>
  <div style="float: left;">Div4</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3sfa0jc1/

Answer (score -1):

You need to be careful with floats, there are for float elements, not to design layout. I recommend that changes floats by displays. Otherwise, I solve your issue with floats.

You can view it running: http://jsfiddle.net/h5o50n41/

The code:

```
<div style="float: left; width:182px; height:200px; border-style: solid; border-width:1px"> Left Column </div>   
<div style="float:left;margin-left: 200px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px"> 

   <div style="float: left; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;"> Div1 </div>
   <div style="float: left; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;"> Div2 </div>
   <div style="clear:left;float:left; width:100%; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;"> Div3 </div>  
   <div style="float: left; border-style: solid;border-width:1px;"> Div4 </div> 
</div>
```